# How to use Moq framework to unit test azure service fabrics?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, moq, azure-service-fabric

I am planning to use Moq for unit testing my azure service fabric application. I saw some of the examples here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/blob/master/ReferenceApp/Inventory.UnitTests/InventoryServiceTests.cs. The test I saw seems like actually writing to reliable dictionary and not mocking. Is there way to mock the add/remove from reliable dictionary? How do I unit test something like below

```
public async Task<bool> AddItem(MyItem item)
{
    var items = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<int, MyItem>>("itemDict");

    using (ITransaction tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        await items.AddAsync(tx, item.Id, item);
        await tx.CommitAsync();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First set up your DI in your services so that you can inject a mock `StateManager`. You can do that using a constructor that takes an `IReliableStateManagerReplica` as a parameter

```
public class MyStatefulService : StatefulService 
{
    public MyStatefulService(StatefulServiceContext serviceContext, IReliableStateManagerReplica reliableStateManagerReplica)
        : base(serviceContext, reliableStateManagerReplica)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in your tests, when you're creating your system under test (the service), use a mock `IReliableStateManagerReplica`

```
var reliableStateManagerReplica = new Mock<IReliableStateManagerReplica>();

var codePackageActivationContext = new Mock<ICodePackageActivationContext>();
var serviceContext = new StatefulServiceContext(new NodeContext("", new NodeId(8, 8), 8, "", ""), codePackageActivationContext.Object, string.Empty, new Uri("http://boo.net"), null, Guid.NewGuid(), 0L);

var myService = new MyService(serviceContext, reliableStateManagerReplica.Object);
```

And then set up the `reliableStateManagerReplica` to return a mock reliable dictionary.

```
var dictionary = new Mock<IReliableDictionary<int, MyItem>>();
reliableStateManagerReplica.Setup(m => m.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<int, MyItem>>(name).Returns(Task.FromResult(dictionary.Object));
```

Finally, setup any mock behaviors on your mock dictionary.

Edit: Updated sample code to use Moq properly.

Comment: with your solution, StatefulServiceContext and MyService do not like Mock<ICodePackageActivationContext> and Mock<IReliableStateManagerReplica>

Comment: Looks like I was missing .Object in a couple of places. I've been using NSubstitute for too long :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without needing to add a `IReliableStateManagerReplica` to my service's constructor?  Can I instead add some data to `StatefulServiceContext`?  Basically, what's the `EntryPoints.CreateReliableStateManager(context)` expecting to be in StatefulServiceContext?