# Specific questions about unit-testing Service Fabric Applications using Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, azure-service-fabric

This question is a follow up to: [Writing UnitTests for a Service Fabric Application Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321526/writing-unittests-for-a-service-fabric-application-class)

My application definition is of the type - simplified it to solve the most basic of problems I am facing:

```
namespace SearchService
{
    internal sealed class SearchServiceClass : StatelessService
    {
        //variables defined followed by constructor
        private string jsonStr;
        public SearchServiceClass(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            try
            {
                var dataPackage = Context.CodePackageActivationContext
                .GetDataPackageObject("Data");
                jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(dataPackage.Path + @"\data.json");
            }
            catch
            {
                //exception handling code
                throw;
            }
        }
        
        public bool IsDataJsonLoaded
        {
            get
            {
                return !(jsonStr == null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the test class looks like:

```
namespace SearchService.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SearchServiceClassTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SearchServiceClassConstructor()
        {
           var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass(MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default);
           Assert.IsTrue(searchServiceClass.IsDataJsonLoaded);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get is that **"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**" which is arising from the fact that "dataPackage.Path" is not being set to a valid value in the "var dataPackage = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetDataPackageObject("Data");" line.

How do I replicate the CodePackageActivationContext using the mock? The "Data" here refers to DataPackage which is a folder by the name "Data" and resides with the code for the SearchServiceClass.

Comment: @LoekD : Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You must mock `StatelessServiceContext` and pass that mock to `SearchServiceClass`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - Edited. Sorry, that was a typo. I had already solved that previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below piece of code to mock the line:

```
var codePackageActivationContext = new Mock<ICodePackageActivationContext>();
```

For more information, check this out: [How to use Moq framework to unit test azure service fabrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464593/how-to-use-moq-framework-to-unit-test-azure-service-fabrics/37465830)

For below query:

> Some thing else I don't completely understand, are variables and
> members being created in the class, but before the constructor is
> called. For e.g. "private string jsonStr;" line does seem to get
> executed without fuss in the Unit Test, even though I am only calling
> the constructor in the Unit Test, and the "private string jsonStr;" is
> outside the constructor. So will the same apply to all the variables
> created outside the constructor?

Here, it is about a simple C# code : In the line `private string jsonStr;`, jsonStr is defined. But, before referencing it, you should initialize it, otherwise it will throw null reference error - which you are doing in your constructor.

Comment: I am using the ServiceFabric.Mocks Nuget package. Could you please tell me how to mock the CodePackageActivationContext using the ServiceFabric.Mocks Nuget package instead of the Moq framework?

Comment: If you just want to use Servicefabric.Mocks, you can use MockCodePackageActivationContext: https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks